# MatchIt - how to make matching date specific?

Tags: matching, nearest-neighbor, mahalanobis, propensity-score-matching

I'm trying to use MatchIt to create two sets of matched investment companies (treatment vs control).

I need to match the treatment companies to the control companies using only data from the 1-3 years proceeding the treatment.

For example if a company received treatment in 2009, then I would want to match it using data from 2009, 2008, 2007 (My after treatment effects dummy would hold a value from 2010 onwards in this case)

I am unsure how to add this selection into my matching code, which currently looks like this:

matchit(signatory ~ totalUSD + brownUSD + country + strategy, data = panel6, method = "full")

Should I consider using the 'after' treatments effects dummy in some way?

Any tips for how I add this in would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to do this in `MatchIt`. You can set a caliper, which requires the control companies to be within a certain number of years from a treated company, but there isn't a way to require that control companies have a year strictly before the treated company. You can perform exact matching on year so that the treated and control companies have exactly the same year using the `exact` argument.

Another, slightly more involved way is to construct a distance matrix yourself and set to `Inf` any distances between units that are forbidden to match with each other. The first step would be estimating a propensity score, which you can do manually or using `matchit()`. Then you construct a distance matrix, and for each entry in the distance matrix, decide whether to set the distance to `Inf`. FInaly, you can supply the distance matrix to the `distance` argument of `matchit()`. Here's how you would do that:

```r
#Estimate the propensity score
ps <- matchit(signatory ~ totalUSD + brownUSD + country + strategy, 
              data = panel6, method = NULL)$distance

#Create the distance matrix
dist <- optmatch::match_on(signatory ~ ps, data = panel6)

#Loop through the matrix and set set disallowed matches to Inf
t <- which(panel6$signatory == 1) 
u <- which(panel6$signatory != 1)

for (i in seq_along(t)) {
  for (j in seq_along(u)) {
    if (panel6$year[u[j]] > panel6$year[t[i]] || panel6$year[u[j]] < panel6$year[t[i]] - 2)
      dist[i,j] <- Inf
  }
}
#Note: can be vectorized for speed but shouldn't take long regardless

#Supply the distance matrix to matchit() and match
m <- matchit(signatory ~ totalUSD + brownUSD + country + strategy, 
             data = panel6, method = "full", distance = dist)
```

That should work. You can verify by looking at individual groups of matched companies using `match.data()`:

```r
md <- match.data(m, data = panel6)
md <- md[with(md, order(subclass, signatory)),]
View(md) #assuming you're using RStudio
```

You should see that within subclasses, the control units are 0-2 years below the treated units.